# Xsockets server with WebForms

Tags: webforms, xsockets.net

I need some help with setting up an XSockets server with WebForms, that waits for a connection from client. I managed to do this locally, but not on a remote server. 
If I try to connect with the client to the server, the onOpen event is not triggered (I've opened a port on the server).

Could you please provide me a tutorial or some guidelines to do this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps [here](http://xsockets.net/docs/installing-xsocketsnet#install-into-a-webapplication) and then connect like [here](http://xsockets.net/docs/javascript-client-api)

Or even better, install the XSockets.Sample.Stockticker from nuget and then follow the instructions given in the file displayed after install.
That way you will be getting more understanding of the basics and wont need to struggle with getting the server running.

```
Install-Package XSockets.Sample.Stockticker
```